# Merging entity framework migrations out of order

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Our code is first deployed to a development server.  When a change-set has passed testing it is merged to a different code branch and deployed to an integration server.  Often we merge a subset of the development migrations to the integration server and the migrations are usually out of order.

We frequently get the entity framework error:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled.

This is because the latest migration model does not match the actual code.  The latest model contains a snapshot of the entities in the development branch but some of those entities have not been merged to the integration server.

I can sync the model with `add-migration -ignorechanges`, but I prefer not to introduce migrations to the integration server that are never on the development server.  Also, we should be able to merge and deploy without altering code or using visual studio.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?
Can `migrate.exe` ignore or suppress this message?

I am using 4.7.2 framework with EF 6.0.0.0.